# Form submit in JQuery code does not fire when I pass Id along with enctype for image upload

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

When I use Id along with enctype in my code then my JavaScript does not hit.

Can anyone please show me the way to do this?

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("_Edit", "Home", new {@Id = "Editform" }, FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"  }))
```

JQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("_Edit", "Home")';
        $('#Editform').submit(function () {
        if (!$(this).valid()) {
        return;
        }
        $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
        $('#Editform').get(0).reset();
        }
        else {
        var message = response.message;
        alert(message);
        }
        });
        return false;
        })
        });
```

Comment: You need to use $.ajax() and `FormData` (with the correct ajax options) if you are wanting to upload a file using ajax - refer [How to append whole set of model to formdata and obtain it in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681) for an example

Comment: And you form does not have an `id="EditForm"` - your overload of `BeginForm` is adding a route value, not a `id` attribute to the form

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you for your comment.I do not understand how to create `FormData`. Please post sample answer based on my scenario.

Comment: See the link I gave you

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I did not understand `var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));` code and how it relates to my problem and also mentioned `controls inside <form> tags`

Comment: Read the 2nd comment for the reason your script does not execute - its `@using(Html.BeginForm("_Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "Editform" , enctype = "multipart/form-data"  }))`. And if you try the code in the link, you will see that it works!

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Sorry to interrupt you. I have added something like this and removed above JQuery code. `var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));
  $.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("_Edit", "Home")',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formdata,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
});` But not working. Please help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176757/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mvc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your script does not execute is that your `<form>` does not have a `id="Editform"` attribute. The overload you are using is adding `Editform` as a route value, not a html attribute. If you inspect the html you are generating, you will see `<form action="/Home/_Edit/Editform enctype="multipart/form-data" .... >`

To add the attribute it would need to be

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("_Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Editform", enctype = "multipart/form-data"  }))
```

However, the fact you have added the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` suggests you are also wanting to upload a file which will not work using the `$.post()` function. Instead, use `FormData` and `$.ajax()` with the correct ajax options as explained in [How to append whole set of model to formdata and obtain it in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681).

Comment: Thank you Stephen for your great help. You saved my hours.